# Deserialize JSON into Object C# without name

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, comments

I would like you to help me with this, I use a web service that responds to a json like a this:

```
"\"{'resultado':'-7','descripcion':'El campo \\\"direccion\\\" es obligatorio'}\""
```

And i'm try to deserialize with a class but get a error.

This is my class

```
public class PanelReyResponseModel
    {
        public string resultado { get; set; }
        public string descripcion { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my code

```
var result = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;

if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   var json = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
   var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PanelReyResponseModel>(json);
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As you probably know, we expect questions to be "a question". Do you have a question here? There is a problem in the code posted? If yes what is? For future reference please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Like Steve mentioned, you'll want to phrase things as questions here, so we know specifically what you need help with.

We could use a little more detail about the problem you're having. For instance, you didn't show us what the error is that you're getting.

Comment: Sometimes you don't know which question to ask...
Where did you get the shown json data from? The text you show contains escapecharacters (\) which would give some very strange results, when you try to deserialize.

Comment: What sort of error do you observe? Could you please share with us the exception's details?